# How to add a plus sign in a file

Tags: awk

I have a file like the follwing

```
 5.0000000000E-02 5.0000000000E+00 4.1000000000E-01 -4.8481128146E+01
 1.5000000000E-01 5.0000000000E+00 4.1000000000E-01 -4.6562934242E+01
 2.5000000000E-01 5.0000000000E+00 4.1000000000E-01 -4.8195946988E+01
 3.5000000000E-01 5.0000000000E+00 4.1000000000E-01 -4.8049939917E+01
 4.5000000000E-01 5.0000000000E+00 4.1000000000E-01 -4.8889348587E+01
-4.5000000000E-01 5.1400000000E+00 4.1000000000E-01 -4.8057104326E+01
-3.5000000000E-01 5.1400000000E+00 4.1000000000E-01 -4.8283429276E+01
-2.5000000000E-01 5.1400000000E+00 4.1000000000E-01 -4.7437231831E+01
-1.5000000000E-01 5.1400000000E+00 4.1000000000E-01 -4.7385816584E+01
-5.0000000000E-02 5.1400000000E+00 4.1000000000E-01 -5.1062140749E+01
```

I would like that all the positive number (in particular of the first column) will be replaced with a + before the actual number..Any ideas?

Comment: you have tagged with `awk`, so do you want only solutions involving it?

Answer (score 3):

use `printf` with `%+e`:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) printf("%+e ", $i)}' a
```

> +5.000000e-02 +5.000000e+00 +4.100000e-01 -4.848113e+01 +1.500000e-01 +5.000000e+00 +4.100000e-01 -4.656293e+01 +2.500000e-01 +5.000000e+00 +4.100000e-01 -4.819595e+01 +3.500000e-01 +5.000000e+00 +4.100000e-01 -4.804994e+01 +4.500000e-01 +5.000000e+00 +4.100000e-01 -4.888935e+01 -4.500000e-01 +5.140000e+00 +4.100000e-01 -4.805710e+01 -3.500000e-01 +5.140000e+00 +4.100000e-01 -4.828343e+01 -2.500000e-01 +5.140000e+00 +4.100000e-01 -4.743723e+01 -1.500000e-01 +5.140000e+00 +4.100000e-01 -4.738582e+01 -5.000000e-02 +5.140000e+00 +4.100000e-01

Answer (score 2):

Use awk to check if first column doesn't already start with a digit and if yes then put a `+` before it:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]/ {$1 = "+"$1}'1 file
```

For putting + before all columns use:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i ~ /^[0-9]/) printf("+"); printf("%s ", $i);}
      print "";}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `+` to first column:

```
awk '{$1=$1>0?"+"$1:$1}1' file
```

Add `+` to all columns:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=$i>0?"+"$i:$i}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

#### GNU sed

for initial example (`5.00..`):

```
sed -r 's/(^|[^-])\b([0-9])\./\1+\2./g' file
```

.

for revised example with leading space for pos. numbers in the first column ( `5.00..`):

```
sed -r 's/^\s([0-9]\.)/\+\1/;s/(\s)([0-9]\.)/\1+\2/g' file
```

.

..output:

```
+5.0000000000E-02 +5.0000000000E+00 +4.1000000000E-01 -4.8481128146E+01
+1.5000000000E-01 +5.0000000000E+00 +4.1000000000E-01 -4.6562934242E+01
+2.5000000000E-01 +5.0000000000E+00 +4.1000000000E-01 -4.8195946988E+01
+3.5000000000E-01 +5.0000000000E+00 +4.1000000000E-01 -4.8049939917E+01
+4.5000000000E-01 +5.0000000000E+00 +4.1000000000E-01 -4.8889348587E+01
-4.5000000000E-01 +5.1400000000E+00 +4.1000000000E-01 -4.8057104326E+01
-3.5000000000E-01 +5.1400000000E+00 +4.1000000000E-01 -4.8283429276E+01
-2.5000000000E-01 +5.1400000000E+00 +4.1000000000E-01 -4.7437231831E+01
-1.5000000000E-01 +5.1400000000E+00 +4.1000000000E-01 -4.7385816584E+01
-5.0000000000E-02 +5.1400000000E+00 +4.1000000000E-01 -5.1062140749E+01
```